# error: no matching function for call to 

Tags: c++, oop

i want to use a method of anothre class in another one,but i get error below,whats the problem?
TIA

error: no matching function for call to ‘PositionInfo::PositionInfo()’

here is my code:

```
PositionInfo Pos;

double metr=Pos.GetBallDistToTeammate(5);
```

and PositionInfo.h class is:

```
PositionInfo(WorldState *pWorldState, InfoState *pInfoState);
```

and PositionInfo.cpp class is:

```
const double & GetBallDistToTeammate(Unum unum) const { Assert(unum > 0); return GetBallDistToPlayer(unum); }
```

Comment: Uh... you seem to have forgotten some parts of your question...

Comment: again corrected,so sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default constructor `PositionInfo::PositionInfo() { /* code */}`  is missing in your cpp file.

Comment: And, presumably, in `PositionInfo.h`.

Comment: But that is usually not a problem, since C++ automatically defines the default constructor for you if you don't define one yourself. Why doesn't that happen in this case?

Answer (score 2):

> error: no matching function for call to ‘PositionInfo::PositionInfo()’

This seems like someone tries to call a default constructor for the class, but the compiler cannot find one.