# "error: no matching function for call to" and I can't change the definition of the struct

Tags: c++, c++98

I am trying to use a struct that is defined this way:

in file number 1 the struct is defined (I can not modify this file):

```
struct prueba
    {
        prueba(int const & a_):a(a_)
        {};

        int a;
    };
```

then in a header the struct is declared as a variable of a class:

```
prueba st_prueba;
```

then in a source file the constructor of the struct is called in a member function of the class:

```
st_prueba(3);
```

and I am getting the next error:

error: no matching function for call to 'main()::prueba::prueba()'

I have seen the answer to this problem in other questions:

[error: no matching function for call to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361705/error-no-matching-function-for-call-to)

where they say that you have to add a default constructor. However in my case, I do not have control over the definition of the struct.

The idea is to have two different steps in order to place the declaration in one file and the call to the constructor in a different file.

How should I do it to be able to use this code?

Comment: prueba st_prueba(3);

Comment: You cannot create uninitialized object and then initialize it. C++ does not allow semi-constructed objects.

Comment: Is `st_prueba` supposed to be a global variable? If not, what do you mean by "declaration in one file"?

Comment: I have edited the question so now it is clearer.

Comment: By "declaration in a file" I mean that this struct is declared in a different file and I do not have writing permission in that file.

Answer (score 5):

In the absence of a default constructor, you must call an existing one. That's what you are currently not doing. But this should work:

```
prueba st_prueba(3);
```

Comment: Ok. I am not an expert programmer and there is obviously something that I am not understanding. Why I can do: int a; a = 1; and however I can not do what I wrote in my question? I would like to define the struct in a file prueba st_prueba; And call to the constructor in a different file st_prueba(3);

Comment: The type `prueba` and the type `int` fundamentally differ. `int` is builtin, but `prueba` is user defined. The ways `prueba` can be instantiated depend on how it is declared. Take your time reading a good book for the start, this might help a lot in approaching these things.

Comment: @mjcmsp You can write `int a(1);` but you can't write `int a; a(1);`.

Comment: So for your answer I assume the only way is prueba st_prueba(3); right? My original idea was to do in two steps in order to use 2 different files. One for the declaration and another one for calling the constructor.

Comment: You can declare a variable without initialising it and then initialise it in your second file.

Comment: How would you do that? Because that is what I am trying to do and I get the error message.

Comment: How are you declaring the variable? As a global variable? A class member? something different?

Comment: As a class member